# When is an algebra a container? Can we compute the container for an algebra?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Containers capture data structures like lists, bags and trees.  Containers can be monads and comonads [as we see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5809).  There is a fascinating link between containers and algebras.  For instance, take the List container which is also a monad.  Lists are also monoids and in fact the theory of the List monad is the category of monoids which "factorizes" the List monad in that it admits an adjunction that generates the monad.

To be more specific, a container is defined by two sets, $S$ and $P$.  The set $S$ is the set of shapes, while the set $P$ is the set of positions.  In the case of Lists, the set of shapes is $\mathbb{N}$, the natural numbers.  We understand this to mean that a list of length $n$, has a shape equal to the natural number $n$.  The set of positions for the list of length $n$ is $Pn = \{ 0 , 1, 2, n-1 \}$.  We take this to mean that $0 \in Pn$ is the first position in the list of length $n$.

Containers are synonymous with polynomail functors.  The data the defines a container are precisely the following morphisms in a locally Cartesian closed category $C$:

$$ 1 \xleftarrow{\text{f}} X \xrightarrow{\text{g}} Y \xrightarrow{\text{h}} 1 $$

Where $1$ is the terminal object in $C$.  This defines an endofunctor for which there is a monad.  Specifically, the endofunctor is :

$$ C/W \xrightarrow{\text{f^* }} C/X \xrightarrow{\Pi_g} C/Y \xrightarrow{\Sigma_h} C/Z  $$

We are interested in endofunctors so $W$ and $Z$ are $1$ in $Set$.

where $\Pi_g$ and $\Sigma_h$ are the dependent product and dependent sum operations.

I am interested in $C$ being arbitrary, but it is most often understood to be $Set$.

We have an endofunctor for which there is a monad or comonad or perhaps both.  To each of these corresponds either an algebra, coalgebra or bialgebra.  So that is one direction.  I am wondering about the other direction.  Given an algebra, when do we know there is a container.  Can we compute it?

I am using the words "an algebra".  By this I mean two things.  First, I mean a category of algebraic structures like the category of monoids.  I also mean a single algebraic structure, such as an algebra over a field,  or a single group.  If one asks, "when is a group a container?",  I am thinking of the question, "does the category of groups factorize a polynomial endofunctor?", which I am calling a container.

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else I can add.

Comment: In the display that's supposed to define an endofunctor, I don't know what$W$ and $Z$ are supposed to be, though I expect, in view of the preceding display,that they're both just $1$ (thereby justifying the terminology **endo**functor). Furthermore, the directions of all the functors in the second display are the opposite of what I'd expect from the first display.  That is, $f^*$ means (to me) pullback along $f$ and should go in the opposite direction from $f$, while the right and left adjoints $\Pi_g$ and $\Sigma_f$ should go in the same direction as $g$ and $h$. So it's still unclear to me.

Comment: i believe i fixed the error for w,z.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by algebra? Do you mean algebra of a monad? So a characterization of when a monad is polynomial?